# Install SharePoint Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-apps

I created a SharePoint Hosted App and it is running on test environment. But when i try to install the same app. It takes long time and gives error "It take too long time". Any ideas about that?

Comment: How are you trying to install the app on your production environment?

Comment: I have an app catalog site. I am adding *.app file there and creating app with "Add an app" site action